# How to automatically adjust the TextView height according to the size of the String?

Tags: android, textview, size

I want to know how to automatically adjust the size of the `TextView` according to the length of the `String`. I am getting some data from another `Intent` as a `String` and storing it in a `TextView`. If I leave it small, the whole text won't fit and only half of it is displayed. If I leave a big space for the `TextView` it does not look nice on the screen.

The solution I found online was using `extends TextView` and using this method gives errors in my class and I have to change a lot of functions because of this

Comment: Why would you adjust *height* according to the *length*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a multi-line TextView and set `layout_height` to `wrap_content`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Note: If you set `layout_width` to `wrap_content` it won't work properly. If you don't want the `TextView` to take up the entire width of the parent view then either:

- Set it to a fixed width in XML, or
- Set the width programmatically, or
- Set `layout_alignLeft`/`layout_alignRight` etc in a `RelativeLayout`
- Set the `layout_width` to `0dp` and use a `layout_weight` in a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little why it won't work when setting layout_width to wrap_content?

Comment: @katie from memory if you do that then the width is set to the length of the string with no line wrapping and it just extends off the right side. It needs to be given a width not equal to the total length to know where to wrap to the next line. As for why it isn't smart enough to line wrap based on the parent view's width I don't know, that's an implementation detail of the Android layout system.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using xml file, just do this,

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="false"/>
```

And if you want to do dynamically do like this,

```
TextView textView= new TextView(activity);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(param);
```